# Singleton that can be inherited: How to cause __init__ to be called once ever using a metaclass?

Tags: python, oop, singleton, metaclass

My initial problem was creating a Singleton metaclass to allow any class to behave as a Singleton like so

```
class A(metaclass=SingletonMeta): pass
```

Another requirement was that any deriving class should also become a Singleton, which I almost achieved by

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

and the usage

```
class A(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, resource_name):
        print(resource_name)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, resource_name):
        super().__init__(resource_name)
        print(resource_name)


def main():
    a = A("A")
    b = B("B")
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### The problem

I want to allocate a resource on `__init__` time of `A`, (once per class), regardless of inheritence. The resource can't be a static variable of `A` because it is dependent on resources that arrive at runtime.

I want resources defined in `A`'s `__init__` to only be allocated once.

What happens is `A.__init__` is also called via `B`'s `super()`, which I am looking to somehow avoid, given that `A`'s `__init__` was already called prior to this.

---

The above code outputs

```
A
A
B
```

but I need it to somehow output

```
A
B
```

---

What can be done, without rewriting `A` and `B`?

I am guessing I should somehow dictate the behavior of `__init__` of the instances of `SingletonMeta`, but not sure this is even doable.

I am out of ideas

---

### Why I believe this is possible

The following

```
class SomeMetaclass(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # this is how to initialize a class (A) which is an instance of SomeMetaclass
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):s
        print("SomeMetaclass")
        # instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        # return instance


class A(metaclass=SomeMetaclass):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(B, self).__init__(arg)
        print(arg)
        pass

a = A("A")
b = B("B1")
```

outputs

```
SomeMetaclass
SomeMetaclass
```

Whereas the following

```
class SomeMetaclass(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # this is how to initialize a class (A) which is an instance of SomeMetaclass
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        print("SomeMetaclass")
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance


class A(metaclass=SomeMetaclass):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(B, self).__init__(arg)
        print(arg)
        pass

a = A("A")
b = B("B1")
```

outputs

```
SomeMetaclass
A
SomeMetaclass
B1
B1
```

showing that the `__init__` can be overridden, and probably so does the behavior of `super()`

Comment: You will call `A.__init__` in `B.__init__`, so when you call `B.__init__`, you must call `A.__init__` without overwriting `A` and `B`.

Comment: @MechanicPig Please see edit. I believe this *is* doable

Comment: It's still not feasible. You just don't call the `__init__` of both in the metaclass, but once you call `B.__init__`, `A.__init__` will definitely be called.

Comment: @MechanicPig alright then, is there another way to create a REALLY singleton, such that it can't be worked-around by a call to `super`?

Comment: I suspect you misunderstood the role of `__init__`. `A.__init__` is called twice does not mean that you have created two instances of `A`. In my opinion, your program works well, and each class does create its own singleton.

Comment: @MechanicPig Hmm, that is a good point to note. Indeed a single instance is created. I do still want to enforce only a single *initialization* by a metaclass. Is that doable in any way?